# Click and Open target in new tab with target="_blank" by jquery/Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Trying to open all links Target in new tab with target="_blank" of specific div `<div class="widget-content">` on click by jquery/Js. Means when we click any links of div `widget-content` links will open in new tab on any browser.

**HTML:** [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/) >

```
<div class="widget-content">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/slycolor"> <b>1k</b></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">  <b>3,200</b></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/"> <b>507</b></a></li>
<ul>
</div>

<div class="widget-content-2">
<ul>
<li><a href="https://twitter.com/slycolor"> <b>1k</b></a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/">  <b>3,200</b></a></li>
<li><a href="https://plus.google.com/"> <b>507</b></a></li>
<ul>
```

This function should work only in `.widget-content` not for `.widget-content-2`. I can do this by changing html, but trying to do this by Jquery/JS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing selector `$(".widget-content a")` , `e.preventDefault()` , `window.open()`

```
$(".widget-content a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(this.href)
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/2/

Comment: Nice, but when click others links of others div, all div gets deleted. please check your fiddle.

Comment: @Aabira _"Nice, but when click others links of others div, all div gets deleted. please check your fiddle."_ ? Can describe "all div gets deleted." ? , create jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: @zlen  not good, please click links of last div, then all div will deleted.

Comment: @Aabira please edit your post with more code, we don't understand what is wrong

Comment: @guest271314  jsfiddle to demonstrate (others links of others div, all div gets deleted): http://jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/1/

Comment: @Aabira Appear to return expected result described at OP ? _"Means when we click any links of div widget-content links will open in new tab on any browser."_ ? No links appear "deleted"

Comment: @Aabira Not certain what to check ?

Comment: when click others links of others div, all div gets deleted: http://jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/3/

Comment: Should not open in parent page. only open in new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make all of links of div whose class is `widget-content` to open in a new page

[**JSFIDDLE updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/1/)

```
$('.widget-content a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: Not working, when click links it's open on new links and also load in same parent and when click others links of others div, all div gets deleted. See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/1/

Comment: Everything works on my computer. Links are opened in new tabs

Comment: and also open in parent page.

Comment: @Aabira _"and also open in parent page. "_ Yes, that would be expected result of click on `widget-content-2` `a` elements, as `href` of `widget-content-2` `a` elements point to document from another origin ?

Comment: when click others links of others div, all div gets deleted: jsfiddle.net/zLs296Lu/3

Comment: Should not open in parent page. only open in new tab.

Comment: @Aabira : Please read the documentation and see this example : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open